# How to prevent COM Server EXE to open Command Prompt window

Tags: c++, com, command-prompt

my question may be simple for you, but I have no experience about it. So, the problem is that I have a COM server and it is started from the context of another EXE, and I need to prevent this COM Server application to open a command prompt window, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to source code for the server, change the linker's /MACHINE option.  Project + Properties, Linker, System, SubSystem setting.  And replace the main() function with WinMain().

If you don't have to source code then you could use

```
Editbin yourserver.exe /subsystem:Windows
```

from the Visual Studio Command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Create/compile the executable as GUI application, those do not get console by default.